# Change Soundtrack properties in QT 7 pro - Batch with applescript

Tags: audio, video, applescript, quicktime

I need to change the soundtrack properties (movie properties tool in QT 7 pro) for a whole bunch of video files. The process would be:
in movie properties click on sound track
and then change the assignment of each audio channel from Mono to "center"
save the file(s)

I am completely unexperienced with Applescript but would it be possible to have a script that would automate that process so I can apply it to all the files without having to do it manually on each QT file?

Answer (score 0):

Quicktime's Applescript support is very limited and the Dictionary only provides access to the most basic of functions (e.g., new movie, play, stop). File settings and properties are not exposed via the Applescript API. There *might* be something in the Cocoa frameworks, though that's a guess on my part.